# How to fix encoding without a string argument when encrypting files?

Tags: python, file, encryption, byte, aes

I need to compress a file , read the contents of the file without unzipping it and encrypt the contents.

**SampleFile***

```
Hello,Encrypt me!
```

**Python**

```
import gzip
import shutil
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

#Compressing file
with open('SampleFile','rb') as f_in:
   with opne('SampleFile.gz','wb') as f_out:
     with gzip.GzipFile('SampleFile','wb',fileobj=f_out) as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in,f_out)
#Reading Contents
file_rd = gzip.open("SampleFile.gz","rb")
file_content = file_rd.read()
print(file_content)
print(type(file_content))

#Encryption
def encrypt(key,iv,text):
 try:
   print("Inside encryption")
   aes = AES.new(key = base64.decode(bytes(key,'utf-8')), mode = AES.MODE_CBC, IV=base64.decode(bytes(iv,'utf-8')))
   res = base64.encode(aes.encrypt(pad(bytes(text,'utf-8'),AES.block_size)))
   return res
 except Exception as e:
   print(e)
   return None

key ="##Mykey##"
iv = "##Myiv##"
 
encryption = encrypt(key,iv,file_content)
print(encryption)
```

While encryption,it is giving me an error as **TypeError:encoding without a string argument**
I checked online and i found most of the answers related to the bytes (encoding is the argument of the bytes function).
I even tried:

```
file_content = bytes(file_content,encoding = 'utf-8')
```

How can i fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more detail of the error message?

Comment: Please show a [*complete* error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough).

Comment: ```
Error:
res = base64.encode(aes.encrypt(pad(bytes(text,'utf-8'),AES.block_size)))
TypeError:encoding without a string argument
```
This is the complete error message. @Karl Knechtel @R. Marolahy

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is indicated in the error message: your `text` (which is actually the `file_content`) that you feed to `bytes()` is not a `str` (it is already of type `bytes` from the way you read it with `'rb'`).

Try to remove `bytes()` and it should work:

```
res = base64.encode(aes.encrypt(pad(text, AES.block_size)))
```